# How to insert three pictures into specified three cells in table in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to insert three pictures in consequent manner into three specified cells (2nd row, and columns 1, 3 and 5) in a table in word. I managed to do it only for one picture into one cell:

```
Sub insertSig() ' works only for one picture & one cell only
  Dim fd As FileDialog
  Dim oTable As Table
  Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

  Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(3)

  Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  With fd
   .Title = "Select image files and click OK"
   .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png"
   .FilterIndex = 2

   If .Show = -1 Then

     oTable.Cell(2, 1).Select

     For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

      With Selection
        .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
          vrtSelectedItem _
          , LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
          Range:=Selection.Range
        .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
      End With
    Next vrtSelectedItem

   End If

 End With

 MsgBox "Signature Inserted"

End Sub
```

But I need to insert selected three pictures into raw 2, column 1, 3 and 5.

I imagine that code should look something like this:

```
Sub insertSig2()
  Dim fd As FileDialog
  Dim oTable As Table
  'Dim oTable As Array  
  Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

  Dim Cell1 As Variable
  Dim Cell2 As Variable  
  Dim Cell3 As Variable
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim iCells As Cells

  Set Cell1 = oTable.Cell(2, 1).Select
  Set Cell2 = oTable.Cell(2, 3).Select
  Set Cell3 = oTable.Cell(2, 5).Select

  Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(3)

  Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  With fd
    .Title = "Select image files and click OK"
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png"   
    .FilterIndex = 2

    If .Show = -1 Then

      For Each iCell In iCells
      'or For i = Cell1 To Cell3

        For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
          With Selection
           .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
             vrtSelectedItem _
            , LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
            Range:=Selection.Range
          .MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
         End With
       Next vrtSelectedItem

     Next iCell
   End If
  End With
  MsgBox "Signature Inserted"
End Sub
```

I am thinking of an array function like this

```
oTable.Range(Cell(2, 1), Cell(2, 3), Cell(2, 5)).Select
```

but I cannot figure it out either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something along the following lines - a number of things could change depending on how exactly you want to specify the list of replacement cells:

```
Sub insertSigs() 

' Specify the number of cells
Const pictureCount As Integer = 3
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim i As Integer
Dim oTable As Table
' NB, VBA actually creates an array with elements 0,..,pictureCount
Dim targetCell(pictureCount) As Word.Cell

' Specify the table
Set oTable = ActiveDocument.Tables(3)

' Populate our array of cells.
' We don't need to select anything
' But trying to store the .Ranges rather than the
' Cell object references probably won't work well
Set targetCell(1) = oTable.Cell(2, 1)
Set targetCell(2) = oTable.Cell(2, 3)
Set targetCell(3) = oTable.Cell(2, 5)

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

  With fd
   .Title = "Select image files and click OK"
   .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.bmp; *.tif; *.png"
   .FilterIndex = 2

  If .Show = -1 Then

    For i = 1 To IIf(.SelectedItems.Count < pictureCount, .SelectedItems.Count, pictureCount)
      ' use the Cell Range rather than selecting
      targetCell(i).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
        FileName:=.SelectedItems(i), _
        LinkToFile:=False, _
        SaveWithDocument:=True
    Next
  End If

End With

MsgBox "Signatures Inserted"

End Sub
```

Comment: Cindy Meister & bibadia, thank you so much for responses!!! it works! Unfortunately could not set up the first suggestions, but the last-works! Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good, but hampered by the fact that you can have only one Selection in a Word document. You can, however, have as many Range objects as you need. So:

```
Dim Cell1 As Word.Range
Dim Cell2 As Word.Range  
Dim Cell3 As Word.Range

Set Cell1 = oTable.Cell(2, 1).Range
Set Cell2 = oTable.Cell(2, 3).Range
Set Cell3 = oTable.Cell(2, 5).Range
```

You can assign these to an array and loop them - at the same time you loop the dialog box selection (no need for an additional, nested loop). Or you can do something like this with the dialog box selection:

```
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
         .SelectedItems(1) _
        , LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
        Range:=Cell1
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
         .SelectedItems(2) _
        , LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
        Range:=Cell2
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
         .SelectedItems(3) _
        , LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, _
        Range:=Cell3
```